# Can't connect to MS SQL Server database using SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2005, networking, ssms

I have a database on line with Godaddy (who uses SQL Server 2005). They provide basic management tools, but tell you that for more advanced tools you can connect directly using SSMS. I followed their instructions to ensure my online database will accept remote connections, and can apparently log in using SSMS with success (after giving my hostname and access data).

However: Now from in SSMS, when attempting to expand the "Databases" folder tree, I get the following error:

> Failed to retrieve data for this
>   request.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>
> An exception occurred while executing
>   a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> The server principal "cmitchell" is
>   not able to access the database
>   "3pointdb" under the current security
>   context. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:
>   916)

The irony is that 3pointdb isn't my database. It is just another in a long list of databases that show up when I access my Godaddy backend. From SSMS, I selected the default database to be the name of my database, which it did locate on the list when I browsed. Still same error message. It is trying to connect to a database that isn't mine! :( Godaddy support, after a bit of testing, said the problem isn't on their end. it's on mine.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your host has done the following:

```
REVOKE VIEW ANY DATABASE FROM public
```

...and this prevents browsing the database list in SSMS, although it doesn't stop you seeing that list using other techniques, or connecting to your database in a query window.

I think the only thing you can do is ask them to change it back, or at least to verify that that's indeed what they did.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the default database for the cmitchell server principal got set to the 3pointdb database instead of yours.  You should call Godaddy back and have them check that.